# TexStudio Installation Problems in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installing, editors, ubuntu, texstudio

I want to install TexStudio in Ubuntu 12.04. I cannot find it in Software Center. From command line if I use `sudo apt-get install texstudio` it says unable to locate package. Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TeXStudio isn't in the Repositorys of Ubuntu 12.04. You need to install it manually.

To do this, go [here](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jsundermeyer/xUbuntu_12.04/amd64/texstudio_2.5.2_amd64.deb) for the 64bit Version or [here](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jsundermeyer/xUbuntu_12.04/i386/texstudio_2.5.2_i386.deb) for the 32bit version.

You can install it by simply doubleclicking the `.deb` file.

After updating your system to Ubuntu 12.10 or later you could install TeXStudio using the repository.

Comment: TeXStudio isn't in the Repositorys of Ubuntu... until 12.04.  It's there since 12.10.

Comment: @giordano: Thank you I'll add this to the answer

Comment: The links in this answer are for TeXstudio version 2.5.2. Links to the latest version can be found on the [project's homepage](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/index.html#download).